# How to use Zend Framework 2 on a normal hosting?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I installed Zend following this procedure:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbBt4W65SRk

But when I move around on Altervista.org my project it does not work because I can not make these two changes into the hosting:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
DocumentRoot "/ xampp / htdocs / ZF2 / public"
ServerName ZF2
ServerAlias www.ZF2
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory "/ xampp / htdocs / ZF2 / public">
DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride All
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
</ Directory>
</ VirtualHost>
```

and

```
127.0.0.1 ZF2
```

How can I use Zend locally without moving the root of Zend /public?

How can I use Zend without do two previously changes?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify, are you trying to get this running on altavista hosting or locally?

Comment: Both!
I'm doing a project on XAMPP locally and after I would want to upload file into Altervista hosting using FileZilla.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you mean remote hosting server which is not controlled by ?

Comment: Sure! A classic shared hosting! A free hosting too!

Comment: Hi! Does altavista support htaccess files?

Comment: I don't know, Are there hosting that don't have support for .htaccess file?